# Shouldn't these questions WRT "It Follows" be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates

I watched "It Follows" yesterday, and afterwards I suspected there might be [some questions about it](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/it-follows) on this SE. There are only four, but some of them are troublesome.

(Beware, **spoilers** ahead.)

There are two questions about the ending of the movie:

- [Explanation of the ending of "It Follows"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35876/explanation-of-the-ending-of-it-follows)
- [Ending of It Follows 2014](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36813/ending-of-it-follows-2014)

I feel the second question could probably be closed as a duplicate of the first one... except that there are more questions:

> How should I interpret the redness in the water and why didn't it work
>   before? If that didn't kill it then why would the guy take the 'curse'
>   on himself?

Now, the first one -- about the blood in the water -- is related to the ending and this element is not present in the first question, so ideally the question should have been rewritten to focus on that aspect.

The second one however -- about the guy taking the curse -- is a totally different question altogether.

So [Ending of It Follows 2014](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36813/ending-of-it-follows-2014) should be closed as "too broad", and ideally be split into two questions with one focusing on the redness in the water and the other about the guy taking on the curse voluntarily.

Or am I mistaken?

---

The combination of multiple questions is also a problem in another question: [I think I missed something in 'It Follows'](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31712/i-think-i-missed-something-in-it-follows) , which is reflected in [the structure of the top answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/35118/13595).

IMHO there are two possible solutions: closing the question as too broad and requesting that the original poster splits it up into multiple questions. the same should be applied to the answer, of course. But that would probably be a messy affair, so perhaps the best solution would be to put a historical lock on the question.

---

Yes, there's a bit of irony that this meta question combines multiple questions. I felt it to be overkill to post multiple questions, but I'll happily split it if the community requires it.

Comment: Same movie - different questions about ending, don't waste your time trying to fix something that ain't broken IMHO. If question is same mark it as duplicate if it isn't - don't. This will end up analyzing margin for similarity of question which will be subjective every-time.

Answer (score 0):

If it should, vote to close as dupe, they will go into the review queues and if 4 others agree, they will be closed. As it stands no one else believes they should. Other wise they are non-issues. Six months after they were asked, no one cares that much.

Comment: It actually only takes the original and *four* more to close a post, but I see your point.